# How to correctly use group by in Google Query by one column when I multiselect columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a page in google spreadsheet which contain list of ID's which are used in another page to be a lookup index. Initially I just used VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP functions but now I'm trying to make a Query because it offers more features to represent my data.

Simpler variant of query works fine:

```
=QUERY('Page1'!A3:N;"select E,sum(B) where A matches "*someID*" and E <> '' group by E";1)
```

Trying to get more columns I've modified string to that:

(This query works but don't do what I want)

```
=QUERY('Page1'!A3:N;"select E,H,sum(B),I,J,N,K where A matches "*someID*" and E <> '' group by E,I,H,J,N,K order by N desc";1)
```

I'm trying to group the result of my query by only column E but query language doesn't allow to skip "I,H,J,N,K" columns if I use it in the select part.
that columns "I,H,J,N,K" contains mostly string data, but column E is numeric

I wanna something like this and ask you, fellows to help me correct that string!

```
=QUERY('Page1'!A3:N;"select E,H,sum(B),I,J,N,K where A matches "*someID*" and E <> '' **group by E order by N** desc";1)
```

I expect to get data from a few columns aggregated by COL E as an index

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Second query return the information like that:
art1,info1...
art2,info2...
art3,info3...
art1,info1...

first rerutrn of art1 is from first indexed list, second return of art1 is from other indexed list.
Main goal of spreadsheet is to calulate cost of positions in every indexed list and after that I want to get a list with combined positions across all that indexed lists